# MySQL BULK LOAD INTO Command With Numbers

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a text file I'm trying to load into a MySQL table using the BULK LOAD command.

Here's the table columns:

```
word_id (INT)
coword_id (INT)
total_proximity (DECIMAL (16,9)
```

Here's my statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '<file path>' INTO TABLE cowords_batch (word_id,coword_id,total_proximity)
```

Here's the first few rows from my file (tab-delimited columns):

```
2   363170  0.5833334
2   358315  0.5
2   303582  0.45
2   286098  0.25
2   264910  0.25
```

When I execute the command, I get this error:

```
Incorrect integer value: '﻿2' for column 'word_id' at row 1
```

I don't know whether this means it is interpreting it as a string? I'm sure I'm overlooking something. I've done several searches and only found issues related to strings, but not numbers. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I tested it on MySQL 8.0.29. It was successful, I got 5 rows inserted with no error. Could your file have some extra invisible characters that aren't shown in your question above?

Comment: I think that your file is Windows-style text. You do not specify lines terminator parameter in LOAD DATA, so default UNIX-style terminator is used. Study [LOAD DATA Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) syntax and add complete format definition into your query. PS. Investigate your file content in HEX viewer.

Comment: Thank both of you Bill and Akina. I manually created a file from the sample I have in my question, and it imported successfully. So it would definitely appear to be something with my data which I'll explore now.

Comment: Thank you both. Your comments led me to taking a serious look at the data and that is where the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the issue. I create the file as such:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(<file path>, <string>, Encoding.UTF8)
```

I removed the third parameter

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(<file path>, <string>)
```

and it imported successfully.